# Is there a Hibernate Metrics micrometer available to capture Hibernate/JPA SQL Statements, min, max time

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

HibernateMetrics expose via spring boot actuator does not to capture the SQL statements. The SQL statements are needed to analyze individual query execution plan.

new HibernateMetrics(sessionFactory, "myapp", Collections.emptyList()).bindTo(registry);

Is there a micrometer available for this purpose?